# How to write WHERE clause with a Datetime using Sequelize in Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write this where clause in Sequelize syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE `deleted_at` = null OR `deleted_at` > now();
```

I have sequelized the where clause in several ways including replacing `[sequelize.Op.or]` with just `or`:

```
where: {
  deleted_at: {
    [sequelize.Op.or]: [null, { [sequelize.Op.gt]: (new Date()) }]
}
```

but I must be way off in my syntax because my output shows it is running this query:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `created_at`, `created_by`, `deleted_at`, `deleted_by` FROM `artist` AS `artist` WHERE `artist`.`deleted_at` = '2017-12-22 00:00:00' LIMIT 1;
```

The time is wrong (should show late afternoon, not 00:00:00), it shouldn't show the equals sign, and it doesn't even mention the null. I can't tell what the syntax is from the documentation. Banging my head against a wall here.

Comment: what s the datatype of `deleted_at`

Comment: The data type is Datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this?

```
  where: {
            [Op.or]: [{deleted_at: null}, {deleted_at:  { [sequelize.Op.gt]: (new Date()) }}]
        }
```

I put it in answer section for formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer from xelliof, the operators can also be written without the square brackets as follows, personal preference:

```
    where: {
        $or:
        [
            { deleted_at: null },
            { deleted_at: { $gt: (new Date()) } }
        ]
    }
```